# more on symfony2 doctrine and relations

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

So now I have set up my slideshow containers like:
Geoarea, Building, Server

in different entities, mapped from one superclass.

Now the next problem I face is: I want to be able to relate these containers' contents to either one of the containers...

That was the reason I was initially just contemplating having one container entity and setting containertype with an INT flag, but OO-wise that isn't smooth or correct I think.

Now, I could of course have FK fields in my entity 'content' for each of the possible containers, and set them to nullable and only use one of them, but I feel like I am stuck in a rut here, think outside the box... I want to make fetching a container and it's related contents as simple as possible...

Each content is only related to ONE container, so having 3 FK-fields when never using more than one feels dumb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions. The first is to use Inheritance : [Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), but you will have some redundance in your database.

The second solution is to add a FK in your Child entity and not three in your Mother entity.
Thereby, you will store common data in your Mother superclass.

Comment: Not sure I follow, maybe I was unclear. Lets say I have a geoarea mother entity, and a building mother entity, then I have 3 child entities (slides of the slideshow). Two of these child entities will belong to the geoarea mother entity, and one will belong to the building mother entity. I can't solve this by putting an FK in the mother entity since there is a one-to-many relationship there. One solution would be to put the FK in the child, but then I would need one FK for each type of mother entity right? Seems to become a hassle when doing those forms for the GUI. I will look in to nb1 thanks

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem, but if you have a ManyToOne relation between the child and the mother, it will create a FK in your child referencing your mother.

Comment: I realized I was dealing with one and the same object, so I added a child property container_type and FK:ed that, so now I am only using one entity for all types of containers. Sometimes the planning sidetracks a bit... for me at least =)